# Fetching HTML textfield value using Javasctipt

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

I have a `textfield` which is NOT enclosed in a `form`. Using `javascript` I need to extract the `textfield` value. How can I do this ?

I am using `C#-Razor` in my front end.

**HTML Razor Syntax** : (Note: this `textfield` is not enclosed in a `form`, and I don't want it to be enclosed in a `form`)

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NAME, new { @class = "control-label col-md-12", placeholder = "Name" })
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NAME, new { @class = "col-md-12 " })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NAME)
    </div>
```

**Javascript code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#UseShipAddr').click(function () {
            alert(document.getElementById("NAME"));
        }

 });
```

**Output I get**

> [HTMLInputElement]

Comment: `alert(document.getElementById("NAME").value);` ?

Comment: If your question is simply how to get the value of a textfield, then this isn't a very good question.  You can get the answer to that by simple googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alerting the actual html element itself. You need to get the value like this:
`document.getElementById("NAME").value`